# Syntax Error at line 1: Label can not be 'BRA'

Tags: assembly, syntax-error, motorola, microprocessors, 6800

Getting the error below:

```
Syntax Error at line 1: Label can not be 'BRA'
```

when trying to compile:

```
BRA ND
ND LDAA #0
```

using [sdk](https://www.hvrsoftware.com/6800IDE.zip).

Comment: The error says it all.  What is your question?

Comment: @fuz: The OP wants BRA to be interpreted as an instruction mnemonic, not a label.  Like in their previous question ([Syntax Error: Undefined Label: 'LABELNAME'](//stackoverflow.com/q/60340881)) where BRA LABELNAME worked.

Comment: I'm just studying on the mp. Noting the errors I've had.

Comment: asking a question just so you can answer it is not how stackoverflow works.

Comment: also please dont duplicate questions (and answer both yourself)

Comment: @old_timer Could you refer me to the meta post about it? The ui explicitly allows asking and answering the question at once.

Comment: @old_timer "_asking a question just so you can answer it is not how stackoverflow works._" - That's not correct. Self answers are encouraged on SO. There's even an option to check to ask and answer a question at the same time. See [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/686592)

Comment: @old_timer I am familiar with the rules. You can mark the questions as duplicate for review if you believe such is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembly languages tend to view symbols at the start of the line as labels. Instructions needs to be indented:

```
; Note indentation here
;vv
   BRA ND
ND LDAA #0
```

Comment: IDK about "tend to", unless this is widespread outside of Unix and x86 assemblers.  Many assemblers aren't whitespace sensitive, e.g. the GNU assembler, or any x86 assemblers (NASM, MASM, FASM).  They all use `label:` to disambiguate labels from mnemonics, with the `:` being optional for most (but NASM warns about it).  But clearly this assembler doesn't do that, so keying on text column makes sense as an alternative design.

Comment: @PeterCordes For older systems, like the 6800 CPU tagged, it was very common.

Answer (score 0):

The operation either needs to have whitespace or label in front of it in the right syntax. So replace:

```
BRA ND
```

with:

```
 BRA ND
```

to have:

```
 BRA ND
ND LDAA #0
```